# Installing libsodium to wampserver error function does not exist

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, libsodium

I want to use `libsodium` to work with encryption and secure my data that beeing transferred between server-client. I am working on PHP-PDO application with MySQL as database server, and currently it is in offline mode.

1. I took the lipsodium.dll and add it to the same directory of `php.exe`;
2. I took the `php_libsodium.dll` and add it to:

> C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.10\ext

I then added this script to test if it really exists:

```
var_dump([
    \Sodium\library_version_major(),
    \Sodium\library_version_minor(),
    \Sodium\version_string()
]);
```

I got an error saying:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function Sodium\library_version_major()

Then after few searches online, I changed it to:

```
var_dump([
    sodium_library_version_major(),
    sodium_library_version_minor(),
    sodium_version_string()
]);
```

And still get the error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function
>   sodium_library_version_major()

Answer (score 0):

You need add in php.ini: `extension=php_libsodium.dll`